# How does the iOS app remotely dismiss notifications?

Tags: discussion, notifications, ios-app

I've noticed that the (absolutely awesome) push notifications in the iOS SE app instantly dismiss themselves when they are viewed from the main site. They disappear - which is a great feature. I want to be able to do that in my apps.

How does the iOS app do this? What sekrit thing needs to be sent from the server?

Comment: Aren't programming questions off-topic for meta? :)

Comment: Edit in to describe the framework you use to handle push notifications in your app and flag to migrate this to stack overflow. If you actually have a question on how to use APNS - let's get it to the proper site.

Comment: Undo, posting off-topic questions on meta is a surefire way to sink your results in the upcoming mod election.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Here's the thing: It was borderline when I posted it. The upvotes *seem* to indicate people don't have a problem with it. I flagged for migration a few hours ago, and we're still waiting on that flag.

Comment: To my knowledge, you can send a notification which only sets the badge number - if that goes down, the message associated with that number will go away too.

Comment: Either that, or they're sending a "wake-up" notification to the app (which is available in iOS 7), and simply using local notifications to show the alerts to the user. Thus, the app itself could dismiss the notification.

Comment: @Undo if it wasn't clear, that was a joke. (FYI, good luck! You've got my vote)

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Ah, I didn't catch that. Thanks ;)

Comment: :) A moment later... _This account is temporarily suspended for asking programming questions on MSO. The suspension period ends in 7 days._ +1